# How to read RC file using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I read the content of an RC file (in HDFS) using scala ? I am able to read textfile as well as avro. But not RC file.

Comment: The question is of very low quality. If you want helpful answers, please provide more information and show your effort in solving the problem. Tell us why it does not work, include a stacktrace or error logs.

Answer (score 2):

```
val inputRDD = sc.hadoopFile[LongWritable, BytesRefArrayWritable, RCFileInputFormat[LongWritable, BytesRefArrayWritable]](path)
```

On this RDD you can apply map and read data.

Comment: Thks shekhar
I'm able to read the file using above command. But how to display the content in a console. inputRDD.foreach(println) displays following 
(0,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@256cc644)
(1,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@256cc644)
(2,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@256cc644)
(3,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@256cc644)
(4,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@256cc644)
My actual file is
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
41 42 43 44
51  52 53 54